# Angular - Is it possible to reference colors/styles programmatically?

Tags: css, angular

I have an angular5 application with some animations where I'm changing background/border colors. For example:

```
const blueStyle = style({background: "#0099ff", "border-color": "#0099ff"});
@Component({
animations: [
  trigger("animateOut", [state("true", blueStyle)])
]
...})
export class MyComponent {...}
```

The colors are defined in my sass as variables, so I was wondering if there was any way to reference them, instead of hardcoding them here?

Comment: Can't you use CSS classes for this? then your SASS variables will apply

Comment: How can I change the class in an angular animation? Using classes definitely seems like the best approach, but I'm not seeing how, in an animation, I can change an elements class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

There are few ways you can do that

**[style]**

there is attribute directive through which you can change css property like below

```
// component html
[style.color]="yourColorValue"

// component class ts
yourColorValue = 'red';
```

**[class]**

You ca also define and as per condition you can change them. Incase of class you can handle multiple proplrties as class can hold multiple properties

```
// component html
[ngClass]="isSomeCondition(frmt)? 'recommended' : 'normal'"

// component css/scss file
recommended: {
  color: 'red';
}
normal: {
  color: 'blue';
}
```

Comment: Using classes certainly makes sense, but I'm not sure how I could animate that? For example, say I wanted to have an animation where an element flashes between red and blue. I could define the two classes like you have above, but the @angular/animations has interfaces for creating AnimationStyleMetadata where individual style properties can be changed, but I don't see how to change to a different class altogether?